# Failover Cluster Missing Disks

Tags: powershell, failovercluster, alwayson

I'm stuck with a weird situation to which i could not find a solution.

I Have 3 AWS instances (windows server 2019) joined to a failover cluster and each one of them have an instance store volume which empty itself on every system boot. My task is to initialize that volume on each instance using a script with initialize-disk powershell Cmdlet.

So far that's not a problem but i encountered an issue where running get-disk gives me only 1 row for that volume type (serial number 0078 is the same across the instances) while other volumes are showing from all over the cluster (you can see a few dbdata or dblog disks from the entire cluster). Before adding the instances to the cluster the initialize-disk worked as expected since each instance lived in its own world, but the issue started after adding the instances into the cluster.

[example for get-disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJDda.png)

This situation denies me the option to choose the volume which belongs to that specific instance and initialize it. as you can see in the example the partition style is set to MBR while on the instance itself this volume is uninitialized and unallocated. what you see here as initialized as MBR is in fact from another server in the cluster.

My guess is that since AWS gives this volume type the same details like serial number (always 0078) and also the disk number is the same then get-disk filters out 2 out of the 3 but i couldn't prove it in any way and every method i tried to get data which will allow me to use initialize-disk failed.

Did anyone encounter such an issue before? Thanks